# OnTriggerEnter2D not working Unity Problem

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, triggers, collision

so i've got this problem thats bugging me for hours now.
I try to use `OnTriggerEnter2D();` to get the data of `other.DataHolder.itemType`.
But Unity states that `other` does not contain whatever I'm trying to access.
My first Question is, how should unity know that? As in the moment I write the code there's nothing colliding with my `player` so the code inside of `OnTrigger2D();` shouldn't be executed and therefore not asking for components of nothing that obviously not exist.

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{   
    other.gameObject.GetComponent<DataHolder>();
    if(other.DataHolder.itemType == "bagCoins")
    {
        goldCount++;
        other.GameObject.SetActive(false);
    }


}
```

Comment: That’s not how you use getcomponent. If you want to use that component you need to store it in a variable it doesn’t just mean the “other” will now allow .whatever to work.

Answer (score 1):

> How should unity know that?

Well this is `c#` and any compiler will know the existing types and that a [`Collider2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.html) has no member called `DataHolder`.

> As in the moment I write the code there's nothing colliding with my player so the code inside of OnTrigger2D(); shouldn't be executed and therefore not asking for components of nothing that obviously not exist.

I'll try it in simple words: As with any other application **your entire code is/has to be compiled by Unity before you can even enter the PlayMode/execute it!**

So if there is an error in your code of course you will get the according **compiler error** before it is actually executed since the compiler doesn't even understand how to compile your code for running it.

What you speak about would be a **runtime error** that only occurres e.g. because some reference is `null` but principally means that your code structure itself is correct.

---

`GetComponent` **returns** a reference. Just calling

```
 other.gameObject.GetComponent<DataHolder>();
```

itself does nothing. And in particular it does not change the type of `other` which still is a `Collider2D` and has no such member like a `.DataHolder`!

---

Instead you have to store that returned reference and use it like

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{   
    // no need to go through the gameObject here btw. 
    // the Collider2D inherits from Component which also implements GetComponent directly
    var dataHolder = other.GetComponent<DataHolder>();
    if(dataHolder.itemType == "bagCoins")
    {
        goldCount++;
 
        // Here you want the property gameObject not GameObject
        other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the Fast answer. I just started playing around with unity and c# a few days ago so I still have much to learn. Thank you for explaining in simple words. I'll try this asap and hope this works properly. Have a nice day and thanks again :)